# React, Getting error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jsx

I have a project where I use both react and node (express). When I link to react using *src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"* etc.. I have no problem using react with JSX in the project, but when I try to import like this:

```
import React from "react";
```

I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
This kind of "handicaps" me since I want to use modules like axios etc..

I am not using any module bundler

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I fully understand the question but you seem to be using React.js from a cdn link. With no module bundler. So why are you importing it also? You've already "imported" React.js from your cdn link. =) No need to import it again. The import statement is when you use modules and import them like that with the ES6 syntax. If you want to do that use create-react-app instead.

Comment: I was just using the react import as an example. There are other modules I would like to import. Is there another way without using create-react-app??

Comment: As far as I know you have to use a module bundler like Webpack and also babel if your'e using ES6 syntax like above. Otherwise you have to load your modules by a link like you do with react.development.js

Comment: @weibenfalk I'm trying to find answers to this same issue, and if I split up my code into multiple files, I have to have a script tag in the root html for every single file. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I eventually solved with Browserify. Here's a link to my answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63356350/5132452

Comment: Please do not link to an answer. If the questions are the same, flag the question as a duplicate, or add a comment indicating they are and provide the link. Otherwise, include enough of the answer to answer this question and provide attribution to the authors of the answer and question.