# Using external dependencies in React loaded from CDN

Tags: reactjs, cdn

I'm relatively new to ReactJS and am using it for certain interactive elements within an existing app. I import React and ReactDOM from a CDN:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

And I write my ReactJS in JSX in some .js files that Babel translates and I import like this:

```
<script src="/static/react/NameScores.js"></script>
```

My problem is that I would sometimes like to use external dependencies and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to import them properly.

For example, I want to use react-card-flip. It appears to have a CDN, so I import it like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-card-flip/1.0.10/ReactCardFlip.min.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work. I get a `ReactCardFlip.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at ReactCardFlip.min.js:1` error.

How can I make use of external dependencies with my CDN-based setup? Do I have to use NPM? I have tried, but could not get React to work via NPM, and the CDN is just much easier.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, after much struggle with NPM, I decided to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to import NPM modules directly into my javascript. It works beautifully for what I need.

It works by bundling multiple javascript files into one single file (`bundle.js`). As it does so, it scans through the code for `require(...)` (which is invalid javascript), imports the relevant module and places this directly into `bundle.js`.

I use [Watchify](https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-browserify/using-watchify) to automate this process. A running script keeps an eye out for changes to my code, then runs Browserify on it automatically.

For example, if I want to use `react-string-replace`, I simply do something like this:

```
const reactStringReplace = require('react-string-replace')

mergedPhrase = reactStringReplace(
 mergedPhrase,
 lookup,
 (match, k) => (
 replacement
 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'd recommend you to use npm, you can still use script tags but you must include a module loader, such as RequireJS for UMD builds:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be the best option to move to npm packages. First of all not all packages are available on cdn, secondly it will be hard to maintain versions of packages by using just script tags. I strongly recommend to go to npm/yarn direction and it is more preferable option even from react creators point of view.

You can use for example react create app https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/ easily to start implementing react app and then create dist file which you can include as script tag.

Comment: Thank you. I do think managing React with npm seems most sensible, but I've really struggled to get my head around it. The tutorials refer to creating an app, but my app is not exclusively React. Back-end is Flask and I use React on certain pages to provide interactivity. It's crucial that, if I'm to switch to npm, I can keep my existing React-based pages. Are you aware of any tutorials aimed at such a situation, please?

Comment: In your case I think there will be needed custom solution depending on file structure. I have one more question - for every page you have different javascript file?

Comment: The way I have it set up is that each Flask html template includes a container div and script tags for the .js React files. These files are in my static folder, compiled by Babel from JSX. So yes, each page that contains React also has at least one separate javascript file.